# UNITY - Crashes whenever I try to get a variable from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this simulation where the "Hunter" scans the area with the scannereyes object inside the hunter for an object called "Apple" and whenever it sees the apple its supposed to hunt after it. This is the same with other hunters from the same prefab as there are more hunters on the same platform.

The scanner eyes is supposed to send the data of the apple's position so the hunter can run for it. Ive tried putting the found apple object into static but that would resolve into every hunter hunting for the same apple so I tried instead doing this method:

```
Target = GetComponent<ScannerEyes>().foundobject.transform;
```

And instead of giving the Hunter the data it needed the whole engine just crashes whenever it tries to compile the C sharp code.

Yes everything is well updated and so is my computer. I have a strong enough computer to compile.

```
//In the Hunter CS file
 
void Update()
    {
        if (reproducerate < 1)
        {
            if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Food") != null ) //All apple objects have the tag "Food"
            {
             
                Target = GetComponent<ScannerEyes>().foundobject.transform;
                directiontolookat = (Target.position - transform.position).normalized;
             
 
                if ((transform.position - Target.position).magnitude > Distans)
                {
                    transform.Translate(directiontolookat * Time.deltaTime * Speed);
                }
            }
        }
    }

public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Food")
        {
            reproducerate += 1;
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            Debug.Log(reproducerate);
        }
    }
```

```
//In the ScannerEyes CS file:
 
 
    public bool found = false;
    public GameObject foundobject;
 
    void Update()
    {
//This is only for the scanning sphere to grow overtime cuz thats how scanners work
        if (currentsize != maxsize && !found) {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(currentsize, currentsize, currentsize);
            currentsize += scanningspeed;
        }
 
        if (found)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
        }
    }
 
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Food")
        {
            Debug.Log("WE FOUND IT");
            foundobject = other.gameObject;
            Debug.Log("found at" + foundobject.transform.position);
            found = true;
        }
    }
```

```
//In the Food behaviour CS file (This is just to make it spawn in the world between -4, 4)
 
    private GameObject foodobject;
    public GameObject Foodprefab;
    private float Xspawncoords;
    private float Zspawncoords;
   
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Food is working");
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            Xspawncoords = Random.Range(-4, 4);
            Zspawncoords = Random.Range(-4, 4);
            Debug.Log(Xspawncoords + " and " + Zspawncoords);
            foodobject = Instantiate(Foodprefab,
                new Vector3(Xspawncoords, 1.4f, Zspawncoords),
                Quaternion.identity);
            foodobject.name = "AppleObject";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean under "the whole engine just crash"? If the unity3d editor crashes during the build, you can check log files to get the actual error. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html

Comment: Your food behavior isn’t on the food is it?

Comment: @BugFinder Its a behaviour that the food follows so yea, its in the food prefab

Comment: @Morion It crashes fully, it doesnt give any message on why, it just keep on being on "hold on busy(1m 20s)" or whatever it says, Ive tried waiting 1 hour. It doesnt stop until i end the whole application under my task manager.

Comment: So for every food you spawn. Its spawning more food. That’s why it crashes.

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand if the engine crashes when you start the game or when you just save the scripts.

As far as I can see the Hunter checks that there is at least one GameObject with the "food" tag on it, but you are doing this in the Update() method.
This is very bad for performance since you are calling it every frame, and it's pretty expensive as it's constantly checking for every object in the scene.

You can try removing that call and move it in the Start() method, that would call the method only once!